# Custom Button visibility on Page layout dependent on FLS of some field

Tags: custom-button, page-layout, fls, standardlayout

Is it possible to control Custom Button visibility on Standard Page layout depending on FLS of some field? Or any other way? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is No .You can prevent the functionality of the custom button via validating it once user clicks and proceeds to action but not conditionally display or hide depending on FLS .You will need to override the layout using visualforce.

Comment: Thanks @Mohith, Actually I wanted to have a lock button visible if the user has FLS on Lock___c field. Thanks for the confirmation.